# Create a "regular expressions" that accepts only int and float values

Tags: regex

As the title suggests I would need a "regular expressions" that accepts only integer values ​​and/or float and more with these conditions

- The value must be between 10 and 40
- If it is a float value, accept only one digit after the decimal point
- Example of acceptable values​​: 10 / 20 / 10.5 / 22.6 / 39.9 / 40
- Example of values ​​not acceptable : 10.55566 / 10.10.10 / 10..

i try this , but accepts values ​​that do not follow my conditions described above (unfortunately with regular expressions are not very clever)

```
var regex = /^(?=.*\d)\d*(?:\.\d*)?$/;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex would be:

```
\b(?:40(:?\.0)?|[1-3][0-9](?:\.[0-9])?)\b
```

Where:

- `\b` matches a word start/end
- `[1-3]` limits the first digit to the range 1-3
- `[0-9]` a compulsory digit must follow, thus adhering to the rule 10 <= n < 40
- `(?:..)?` `?` makes the group optionalwithout `?:` disables the capturing of the group
- `\.`  matches a dot literal
- `[0-9]` and exactly one digit

Your check method should be something like

```
var check = function (str) {
    str = str.trim();
    var re = /\b[1-3][0-9](\.[0-9])?\b/;
    match = re.exec(str);
    return match !== null && match[0] === str;
}
```

Alternative:

```
/$\s*(:?40(:?\.0)?|[1-3][0-9](\.[0-9])?)\s*^/
```

Use the latter if you have one string containing the number in question

- `\s*` matches any whitespace characters
- `$` represents the beginning of the string
- `^` represents the end of the string

Comment: this regex : var regex = /\b[1-3][0-9](\.[0-9])?\b/;  accept also 10.10

Comment: it will match `10`, but not `.10`. Because `.` might be considered as a word ending. added check method example that eliminates this problem. PS: why -1?

Comment: This will not match 40: "yes >= 10 && <= 40 "

Comment: updating then we should add and `|40` wasn't sure if inclusive or exclusive inequalities

Comment: now is very nearly perfect, but it is not accepted 40.0 (thanks Matyas , thanks M42)

Answer (score 2):

To match 10<= number <= 40:

```
\b(?:40|[1-3]\d(?:\.\d)?)\b
```